# Whenever Gem - Undefined method '(methodhere)' for User(call 'User.connection' to establish a connection):Class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, whenever

I'm attempting to implement the Whenever gem into my RoR 5 application. Once a year I want it to run a method in my 'User' model, but for testing purposes I have made it once every minute, like so:

Schedule.rb:

```
set :output, "/home/ubuntu/workspace/log/cron.log"

every 1.minute do
    runner "User.(methodhere)"
end
```

User.rb:

```
def (methodhere)
  User.all.each do |user|
    user.update(remaining_days: user.total_days)
  end
end
```

In multiple places I have read that sometimes cronjobs dont run properly in development mode, so I jumped through all of the hoops to put my application into production mode, and that did not help.

I then found that you can manually run these jobs in the command line, which I then tried to do using the command found doing:

```
whenever --update-cron
```

then

```
crontab -l
```

which showed

```
# Begin Whenever generated tasks for: 
/home/ubuntu/workspace/config/schedule.rb
* * * * * /bin/bash -l -c 'cd /home/ubuntu/workspace && bundle exec bin/rails 
runner -e production '\''User.year_days_reset'\'' >> 
/home/ubuntu/workspace/log/cron.log 2>&1'
```

Running

```
/bin/bash -l -c 'cd /home/ubuntu/workspace && bundle exec bin/rails 
runner -e production '\''User.(methodhere)'\'' >> 
/home/ubuntu/workspace/log/cron.log 2>&1'
```

left me with an error in the log, like so:

```
Please specify a valid ruby command or the path of a script to run.
Run 'bin/rails runner -h' for help.

undefined method `(methodhere)' for User (call 'User.connection' to 
establish a connection):Class
```

Many google searches have left me with nothing.

NOTE: Running my method (methodhere) manually in the rails console works perfectly as I want it to. I'm a very new developer with RoR, so any guidance on the matter would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

EDIT: @maxpleaner pointed out I was missing .new in User.new.(methodhere), which fixed the error, however I have a new issue. My code in schedule.rb seems to not be executing anything, as it is supposed to occur every minute but it is doing nothing.

Comment: if your're going to call a method like `User.some_method` it needs to be a _class method_, otherwise use `User.new.some_method`.

Comment: @maxpleaner that was it! Thank you very much, still learning proper ruby syntax, etc so small stupid things like that keep happening to me.

Comment: @maxpleaner while that does solve the error issue, now I have a new issue; my whenever code is not doing anything it seems now. Running User.new.(methodhere) manually in console still does what its supposed to

Answer (score 2):

You have to have an User class method

```
class User
  def self.method
    ...
  end
end
```

In that way you can use User.method in the schedule file.

Comment: If it is now working with User.new.(methodhere) would doing it this way have any effect on it working properly? Also, where would I make this class? Sorry, I'm very new to RoR and proper file placement I'm still working on.

Comment: The way I anwers works without create a new instance of User. If you do User.new you are creating a new instance of user. Instead define a class method and do User.method. If you create a new instance of user you are saving space in memory for that object everytime you run that task, with a class method you avoid that posible memory leak.